# Make a see-through layer

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-graphics, calayer

I am trying to implement erase functionality on my app. For image I can do it with setting bend mode into clear while drawing image with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. Here is the code I have used

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0)
guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
image.draw(in: self.bounds)
context.setLineCap(.round)
context.setLineWidth(5)
context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
context.setBlendMode(.clear)
context.beginPath()
context.move(to: lastStroke.touchPoint)
context.addLine(to: currentStroke.touchPoint)
context.strokePath()
let updatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

It  works fine for images. But I want to implement it on `UILabel`.

One way it can be achieved is by converting `UILabel` into an `UIImage` which will increase difficulty for `UILabel` modification(e.g. change font, spacing). Also this will make it rester.

Is it possible to make a `CALayer`/ `CAShapeLayer` or `UIView` which can be see-through?

[Here is an example I have seen on an app.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tBSybbVyJo5cdCxgK8wE_RFLvu0NNLzT/view?usp=sharing)

P.S: I am not looking for exact code, any implementation idea will be appreciable.
[image]

Comment: Use Core Image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All views in iOS have a "Backing layer", including `UILabel` views. (For Mac OS not all views have layers. For Mac OS NSViews, you have to set the view's `wantsLayer` property to true to attach a layer as the view's "backing store".)

As such, you can install a mask layer on the view's layer. You can make that mask layer a CAShapeLayer, or a regular layer with a CGImage as it's contents.

Don't mess with blend modes. Just add a mask layer to **any** layer that you want to be able to erase/un-erase, including a UILabel's layer

The mask layer will show/hide the contents of the layer it masks. (Opaque pixels in the mask reveal the layer underneath, but clear pixels hide it.)

If you want to be able to do freehand erasing/revealing of things like labels, I would suggest using a layer with an image in it as your mask. Draw opaque pixels into the masks image to "un-erase" the masked image, and draw with clear pixels to erase the masked image. Because you're just changing the mask, the masked image is left untouched.

```
@IBOutlet label: UILabel
var labelMask = CALayer()
```

...

```
func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    // Set up the mask to be the same size as the label view
    labelMask.frame = label.bounds
    label.layer.mask = labelMask
    labelMask.contents = // install a UIImage's CGImage as the contents
    // The rest of your viewDidAppear code goes here...
}
```

### Edit:

I [posted a demo app on Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvERr.png) it that illustrates how to mask ANY view using a CALayer. This demo app uses a CGImage to create a raster mask. You can also use a CAShapeLayer as a vector mask.

Here is the readme from that project:

---

### MaskableImageView

This project demonstrates how to use a `CALayer` to mask a `UIView`.

It defines a custom subclass of UIImageView, `MaskableView`.

The `MaskableView` class has a property `maskLayer` that contains a CALayer.

`MaskableView` defines a `didSet` method on its `bounds` property so that when the view's bounds change, it resizes the mask layer to match the size of the image view.

The `MaskableView`  has a method `installSampleMask` which builds an image the same size as the image view, mostly filled with opaque black, but with a small rectangle in the center filled with black at an alpha of 0.7. The translucent center rectangle causes the image view to become partly transparent and show the view underneath.

The demo app installs a couple of subviews into the `MaskableView`, a sample image of Scampers, one of my dogs, and a UILabel. It also installs an image of a checkerboard under the `MaskableView`  so that you can see the translucent parts more easily.

The `MaskableView` has properties `circleRadius`, `maskDrawingAlpha`, and `drawingAction` that it uses to let the user erase/un-erase the image by tapping on the view to update the mask.

The `MaskableView` attaches a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to itself, with an action of `gestureRecognizerUpdate`. The `gestureRecognizerUpdate` method takes the tap/drag location from the gesture recognizer and uses it to draw a circle onto the image mask that either decreases the image mask's alpha (to partly erase pixels) or increase the image mask's alpha (to make those pixels more opaque.)

The `MaskableView`'s mask drawing is crude, and only meant for demonstration purposes. It draws a series of discrete circles intstead of rendering a path into the mask based on the user's drag gesture. A better solution would be to connect the points from the gesture recognizer and use them to render a smoothed curve into the mask.

The app's screen looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. `using a layer with an image in it as your mask` means converting `UILabel` into image, right?

Comment: No, it does not mean that. Leave the label as a label. Install a CALayer into the label view's mask property. Then manipulate the alpha channel of the mask layer's image to show/hide the layer.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I added a little code to illustrate what I'm talking about. (Not complete code, and it probably has syntax errors - it's just meant to explain the approach.)

Comment: Thanks, adding a masking layer worked like as expected.

Comment: `Then manipulate the alpha channel of the mask layer's image to show/hide the layer`. To do that, I am going with `setBlendMode(.clear)` on  `labelMask`'s `contents` image. As you said I should not mess with blend modes, is there any other way to change `alpha channel` of the mask layer's image?

Comment: Draw with `UIColor.clear.cgColor` (to force the alpha channel for part of the image to 0 or `UIColor.black.cgColor`, or any other opaque color, to force the alpha channel of part of the image to 1.

Comment: Thank you so much for take this much time and making a demo. You are just awesome

Comment: Thank you very much for this demo I was looking for this in a while, I have one issue when I draw it drawing dots not complete lines do you know how to fix this issue ?

Comment: @basel I'm not sure what you mean "it drawing dots not complete lines". Are you saying that if you drag your finger over the image to erase part of it it erases a series of circular areas rather than a smooth path?

Comment: @DuncanC yup that what I meant

Comment: That is beyond the scope of my demo app. You would need to write some drawing code that collected drag points, smoothed them into a curved path, and then rendered the results of dragging a circle along that path. That gets kind of complicated. My demo app uses the naive approach of just stamping a series of circles along each point as you drag your finger, which isn't perfect. (On a decently fast device it's better than "drawing dots", but not perfectly smooth.)